# Eclipse juno does not run after uninstalling some tools

Tags: android, eclipse, uninstallation

I uninstalled all tools shown in the below picture because of [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592359/offline-update-for-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-juno-and-dependency-issues)!

[image]

I just wanted to update ADT after uninstalling.

After restarting, eclipse encountered an error and did not start!

error is:

[image]

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** Log file content:

```
!SESSION 2015-04-13 13:34:13.390 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=
java.version=1.6.0_05
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-04-13 13:34:14.783
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: So? What does the log say?

Comment: Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line. This should start eclipse without any plugins/tools.

Comment: What exactly did you uninstall? Did you uninstall Eclipse related libraries and plugins as well?

Comment: I uninstalled all software shown in the first picture!

Comment: I tried to start eclipse from command line with `-clean` switch but nothing changed!

Comment: You uninstalled `Eclipse IDE for Java Developer`

Comment: You can uninstall or disable remaining plugin through 2 ways : command line : http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fupdate_standalone.html or p2 director : http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html